# Set Cookie from URL

Tags: php, laravel

I'm totally new to Laravel framework just started learning few days back, and I challenged my self to create cookie based URL. Meaning, if I were to access http://localhost/cookie/nick, it should store a cookie based on cookies/*. I tried to do but I get empty cookie each time. Is it possible to do it? If yes can anyone kindly guide me? Here is my code:-

**Routes.php**

```
Route::get('/cookie/{name}','CookieControllerName@setCookieByUrl');
```

**CookieControllerName.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use App\Http\Requests;

class CookieControllerName extends Controller
{
        public function getCookie(Request $request){
                $value = $request->cookie('name');
                echo "Hello ".$value;
        }
        public function setCookieByUrl(Request $request, $name){
                $response = new Response('Hello World');
                $response->withCookie(cookie('name', $name, 3600));
                $value = $request->cookie('name');
                echo $value; //For debugging purpose
        //        getCookie();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the $response variable for anything to happen.

Besides that I don't really see how your code could be working since you have a function call to getCookie() that is not even in the scope. And it should be:

**$this->getCookie()**

Simply replace getCookie() with:

```
return $response
```

Should suffice in atleast getting a proper cookie set.

Complete codeblock:

```
public function setCookieByUrl(Request $request, $name){
        $response = new Response('Cookie has been set');
        $response->withCookie(cookie('name', $name, 3600));
        return $response;
}
```

[image]

Cookie value is encrypted that is why you won't see it directly.

Comment: but the problem is... even the cookie is empty. I tried this... Cookie is empty.

`public function setCookieByUrl(Request $request, $name){
                $response = new Response('Hello World');
                $response->withCookie(cookie('name', $name, 3600));
                $value = $request->cookie('name');
                echo $value;`

Comment: How are you viewing the content of the content and do you atleast have a cookie with "name" set?

Comment: You can try my updated code above, it is empty when I tried to echo

Comment: That is because you never return the $response therefore a cookie will never be set in the first place. If I run your updated code while I already have a cookie in place from my previous working example it gives me a perfect response back.

Comment: Nice! Now I see the cookie is set but how do I call getCookie function? Rather than setting it on routes.php I want it to be called on http://localhost/cookie/{name}

Comment: I think it's do-able if you queue up a cookie but I'm not sure: https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Cookie/CookieJar.html I can't really think of a use case where you would ever implement something in this manner though.

Comment: Thanks! Will look it.